# Председателем избран [или избрана?] Иванова

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, согласование, род

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в договоре верно указать? "Председателем собрания был избран Иванова Елена Сергеевна", или же "Председателем собрания была избрана Иванова Елена Сергеевна"? Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ галочкой, если он оказался полезным.

Comment: Текст скорее из протокола, чем из договора.

Answer (score 2):

Выбор варианта зависит **от наличия нарицательного слова (должности) и от стиля:**

1) Председателем собрания **была избрана** (некто) Иванова Елена Сергеевна.

2) Председателем собрания **был избран** директор ОАО   Иванова Елена Сергеевна (деловой стиль).

3) Председателем собрания **была избрана** директор ОАО   Иванова Елена Сергеевна (свободный  стиль).

Comment: "Был избрана" — описка? Или попытка совместить  несовместимое? :)

Comment: Нет, конечно, это опечатка (клавиатура виновата, я разве так напишу).  Совмещать несовместимое я тоже люблю, но это не тот случай. А Вам спасибо, спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

Корректно:  Председателем собрания был**а** избран**а** Иванова Елена Сергеевна.

В официально деловом стиле сказуемое ставится в мужском роде при отсутствии имени собственного.

Подробно о согласовании в подобных случаях можете ознакомится здесь.  [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89)